# Qt separating csv file and storing to differnt variables

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, c++14, c++17

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include"administrative.h"
#include"employee.h"
#include"technical.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<QVector>
#include<QFile>
#include<QTextStream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile t("C:\\Users\\User006\\Documents\\EmployeeCSV_Vector\\technical.csv");
           
        if (!t.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
            cout << "ERROR: File open";

        QTextStream in(&t);
        while (!in.atEnd())
        {
                         QString line=in.readLine();
           for (int i=0;i<line.size();i++)
            {
               QString item=line.split(",");
                QString name=item;
                QString empCode=item;
                QString designation=item;
                QString prCode=item;
                QString BP=item;
                QString DA=item;
                QString PA=item;
                cout<<name.toStdString()<<"\t";

            }
                       
 }
 t.close();
```

The above code which I wrote is the code that I wrote to separate a CSV file.  The technical.csv file contains some line of values that is separated by commas,  I need each value in each line separately in a different variable. But I am not able to do this. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: why the for-loop?

Comment: Why using Qt for this? Just use a `std::fstream`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the file structure (does it contain line/column headers, single/multi-line?) you use `QString::split()` to get a `QStringList` per line. Then you assign the stringlist items to the variables according to your csv structure knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your code is compiling. According to Qt, the QString::split method returns a QStringList. After the split, you have the items in a list. Assuming all columns are as expected, you can interpret the file as follows:

```
   QTextStream in(&t);
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
       QStringList items = in.readLine().split(',');
       QString name = items.at(0);
       ...
       QString PA   = items.at(6); 
       std::cout<<name.toStdString()<<std::endl;
       // do some processing 
    }
```